# how to create new array from 2 array exist in php

Tags: php, arrays

Hi everyone i have problem with array in php i want to create new array from existing array and get the value of both, i have the code like this:

```
Array(
[header] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [A] => data_nomor_identitas
                [B] => data_map_latitude
                [C] => data_map_longitude
                [D] => data_responden_nik
         )

    )
 [values] => Array
    (
        [2] => Array
            (
                [A] => 32.14.01.06.00000001
                [B] => 0
                [C] => 0
                [D] => 3214000002
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [A] => 32.14.01.06.00000002
                [B] => 0
                [C] => 0
                [D] => 3214000002
            )
        [4] => Array
            (
                [A] => 32.14.01.06.00000002
                [B] => 0
                [C] => 0
                [D] => 3214000002
            )
    )
```

)

then i want the result like this:

```
[values] => Array
    (
        [2] => Array
            (
                data_nomor_identitas => 32.14.01.06.00000001
                data_map_latitude => 0
                data_map_longitude => 0
                data_responden_nik => 3214000002
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                data_nomor_identitas => 32.14.01.06.00000002
                data_map_latitude => 0
                data_map_longitude => 0
               data_responden_nik => 3214000002
            )
        [4] => Array
            (
                data_nomor_identitas => 32.14.01.06.00000002
                data_map_latitude => 0
                data_map_longitude => 0
                data_responden_nik => 3214000002
            )
    )
```

thank's before. sorry for my english

Comment: php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: `array_combine` will be helpful

Comment: From the results I see he says he wants above it looks like he just wants the second array from the parent array set.... if so it would just be
`$new_array=$your_array[1]`...

Answer (score 0):

Give this shot.

[Array combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) uses the values from one array as the keys, and the values from another as the values

```
$newArray=array();


foreach ($array['values'] as $set){
    $newArray[]=array_combine($array['header'],$set);
}

var_dump($newArray);
```